# Need to get different Grey color shade randomly using jquery

Tags: jquery, html, asp.net-mvc-3

I am working on Html 5 Pie charts. In that for each values i need different grey shades. I can have n number of values  so it is not static. Can someone please help me on this so i can generate Random Grey color shade code.

Answer (score 2):

rgb(x,x,x) is gray. Replace x with a random number and you will get different gray colors. Range is rgb(0, 0, 0)(black) - rgb(255,255,255)(white). Examples could be: rgb(5,5,5) or rgb(111,111,111) or rgb(99,99,99).

Comment: Sir i think it will generate different color based on value that range from 0-255. But it can result in color other than Gray as well  like blue ,red etc. I just need Grey color with different shades.

Comment: If u use the same number for red,green and blue channel it will be gray color 100%. Try to generate only 1 number and use it 3 times. If R = G = B the color will be gray.

Answer (score 2):

You need code something like this  :

```
 var a = Math.random() * 254;
 var b = Math.floor(a / 8) * 8;
 $(".greybox").css("background-color", "rgb(" + b + "," + b + "," + b + ")");
```

Here is the working fiddle of the thing you wanted  :

[JS Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/srahel007/XJGss/2/)